# Google maps v2 uthorization failure, could not contact google server

Tags: android, google-maps

I trying to build a simple pedestrian dead reckoniing app using google map v2. But always got error 'Authorization failure' and 'could not contact google server'. I already check the api key, enable the 'Google Maps Android v2' service in Google API console, and allow my apps to use the API. but still not work.

Here's my manifest :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.pdr"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
    <permission
        android:name="com.example.pdr.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.pdr.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-feature 
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.pdr.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.example.pdr.MapActivity"></activity>
        <meta-data 
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" 
            android:value="AIzaSyCu0QDFkPWOOAr0PACX2AUSSGkPWYmdpr0"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here's the activity that using the map

```
public class MapActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private MapView map = null;
private GoogleMap gMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_menu);
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
};

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}

private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    if (gMap == null) {

        gMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
    }
}

private void setUpMap() {
    gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
}
}
```

And finally, here's the layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MapActivity" >

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/map"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Can anybody please help me ? I've been struggling for days..
Thanks in advance, and sorry for my english...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is related to your api-key generation process. Please follow below mentioned steps to generate key-
1. generate SHA-1 using keytool.
2. open google console on browser, dont forget to enable **Google Maps Android API v2** from sevices, now go on API Access, click on create new Android key, paste your SHA-1 along with semi-colon and your project package name then click on create,
3. copy the new API-key and paste in your manifest.
4. Most important, dont forget to import google play service lib from extras folder of sdk if already installed, Otherwise go to Android sdk-manager -> extras->google play service, make it installed then import from your sdk location->extras->google-> google play service.
5. Now add this lib to your working project.

This is the whole process to execute google maps android v2.
Now you can run your project, cheers......